# relation between phase and pole

Tags: induction-motor

In the three phase induction motor 3 pair poles are used.but 
In one phase insduction motor,two poles are used.is it true?
Is Pair of poles indicate the phase .

Comment: No. There are 2 pole 3 phase motors.

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not true. In a three phase induction motor, three sets of windings are used for each pair of poles. The magnetic fields of the three phases are summed together because of the placement and distribution of the windings. The phase displacement of the currents in each phase causes the summation to change during the course of each sinusoidal cycle such that the magnetic poles that are formed rotate around the motor.

Most single phase motors are designed as two-phase motors. The applied power is single phase, but the power applied to one of the two sets of phase windings is connected through a capacitor to create a phase displacement. Single-phase motors are a bit more difficult to explain than three-phase motors. I will not attempt to give a more complete explanation right now.

For a complete explanation of both single-phase and three-phase motors, it is best to consult a text book or detailed course notes which include all of the necessary diagrams and mathematics.

Comment: Some single phase motors use a magnetic shunt (well a shorting loop or few over part of the stator laminations) to generate the phase lag.  These 'shaded pole' motors do not have a capacitor but are also essentially two phase in operation.